# Formatting the default date and time for HSQLDB

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I have been trying to format the date and time in the CREATE command (to apply for cases where user does not enter any value for date/time). According to the manual, there are the TO_DATE and TO_TIMESTAMP format elements. How do I fix my SQL statement? 

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#N142F5

```
CREATE TABLE test1( 
        Id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,

"Date In" DATE DEFAULT TO_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),

"Time In" TIME DEFAULT TO_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIME,'HH:MM')

);
```

I tried with TO_CHAR but still return an error.

https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/Base/HSQLFunctions

[image]

Comment: What error is returned?

Answer (score 2):

DATE, TIMESTAMP or TIME values do not have "a format". They are stored in a binary way and formatted when they are *displayed*. So you can't apply "a format" to a `DATE` column. Additionally, calling `to_timestamp()` on a value that is a date makes no sense. `to_timestamp()` is used to convert a string (character) value to a date (or timestamp).

Just define both columns without (wrongly) applying a conversion from a string to a timestamp:

```
CREATE TABLE test1( 
    Id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    "Date In" DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    "Time In" TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME
);
```

Given the name of the two columns, I think it would make more sense to store that in a single `timestamp` column:

```
CREATE TABLE test1( 
    Id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    "Date Time In" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```